# How to implement basic syntax highlighting in Winforms RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms, richtextbox

I have a list of words I want to highlight in my `RichTextBox` control, I have an idea on how to do it but having a problem with parsing everything to separate words.

How can I parse a line or the whole text into separate words and then enumerate over them and color them using `RichTextBox.Select()` method.

Is this a good way? Is there a better/faster way?

Comment: May the downvoter dare to say why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the RichTextBox.Find(String, Int32, Int32, RichTextBoxFinds)  method to find your strings in the control.  You can then iterate by changing the Start point to the point after the current word.

Not sure on the performance of this scheme but it will work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab8wkhy.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Avalon Edit](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx) instead of a `RichTextBox`, it's free. It is the editor used in [#develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). I think you may have to pull the assembly out of the #develop source download but it is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `string.Split` method. It return you array of strings splitted by delimiter.

Also you may found usefull those links: [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882639.aspx) [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397915.aspx)

And even more: there is a fine [example](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=146) of similar app

Comment: Thanks I tried it now and that should work but then realized how I wouldn't be able to use them for the Select method because I need to know where that word starts, and the case of multiple same words on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RichTextBox.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfcsf75k.aspx) method in order to find a string in your RichTextBox. This method returns the position of the text it found. The code sample in that link will highlight the text.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the fastest way but it works.
First call `ClearHighLighting` to clear previous and then call `SetHighLighting`

```
private readonly List<HighLight> _highLights = new List<HighLight>();
private class HighLight
{
  public int Start { get; set; }
  public int End { get; set; }
}

public void SetHighLighting(string text)
{

    // Clear Previous HighLighting
    ClearHighLighting();

    if (text.Length > 0)
    {
        int startPosition = 0;
        int foundPosition = 0;            
        while (foundPosition > -1)
        {
            foundPosition = richTextBox1.Find(text, startPosition, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            if (foundPosition >= 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                int endindex = text.Length;
                richTextBox1.Select(foundPosition, endindex);                        
                startPosition = foundPosition + endindex;                        
                _highLights.Add(new HighLight() { Start = foundPosition, End = endindex });
            }
        }
    }
}

public void ClearHighLighting()
{
    foreach (var highLight in  _highLights)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = richTextBox1.BackColor;
        richTextBox1.Select(highLight.Start, highLight.End);                        
    }
    _highLights.Clear();
}
```