# Inserting Colored text into a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, richtextbox

I have a `rich textbox` where the user can select keywords from a list and they will be inserted in a different color. The user can also enter their own text. The program will be used to build SQL snippets.

For example, text entered by the user will be black, and keywords from that list will be in blue.

I've seen several examples of appending words of different color, but no examples of inserting words of different colors.

Below is what I have tried

```
        public void InsertText(Color color, string text)
    {
        var startposition = _richTextBox.SelectionStart;
        var endposition = startposition + text.Length;

        _richTextBox.Text = _richTextBox.Text.Insert(startposition, text);
        _richTextBox.Select(startposition, endposition - startposition);
        _richTextBox.SelectionColor = color;
        _richTextBox.Select(endposition, 0);
    }
```

the problem with this code if text is inserted anywhere except at the end, the rest of the paragraph does not retain the color it had previously. Is there a way to insert text of a different color, while not interfering with the formatting of the rest of the text?

Comment: Have you checked this article? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982342/how-to-implement-basic-syntax-highlighting-in-winforms-richtextbox

Comment: What is the magic of `endposition - startposition` instead of `text.Length`? I think your code is not good but it should not cause such a problem you mentioned, maybe it involves some code elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a syntax highlighting control for Windows Forms such as the following ones ?

http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

https://code.google.com/p/alsing/wiki/SyntaxBox

**The first one has SQL support**, it took me less time than writing this post to get the following result using their demo app.:

[image]